# dapper - return a list of INT

Tags: c#, dapper

From a stored procedure I am returning a list of `int` - simply as

```
SELECT ID FROM Table
```

This is using dapper. Below is an attempt of what I am trying to do. I can fill an object in using the same approach but not an `int` object

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>();
int id = 0;

// Trying to fill a list of ints here
ids = connection.Query("storedprocedure", param, transaction: transaction, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).Select(row => new int { id = row.ID }).ToList();
```

I believe its something to do with `=> new int` at the end of the statement. I am sure the solution is fairly simple. Just one of them fridays.

Comment: Try to replace `Select(row => new int { id = row.ID })` with `Select(row => row.ID)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that you should specify the type you expect from your query like below:

```
var ids = connection.Query<int>("storedprocedure", 
                                param, 
                                transaction: transaction, 
                                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

You could check this [Execute a query and map the results to a strongly typed List](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#execute-a-query-and-map-the-results-to-a-strongly-typed-list) for further info.

Answer (score 3):

This is very similar but with `.ToList() as IList<int>`

```
var ids = connection.Query<int>("storedprocedure", 
param, transaction:transaction, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)
.ToList() as IList<int>
```